# how do i substring a line on search of a particular name?

Tags: java, string, split, substring

In my code i have to print the Package name and Class name where ever the line finds "package" and "class".
I know how to substring / split, if the index is known.
As in my case the package name and the class name will change in different files, so bit confused how to do it.
For example :

```
package com.sify;import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteJava{

}
public class WriteJava2{

}
```

The output should be;

Package Name: com.sify
Class Name: WriteJava
Class Name: WriteJava2

Any help is appreciable.

### Thanks In Advance.

Slightly edited my code.
what if some other line is ther after "package com.sify;" as given in the code.
How i ll substring the extra import part.

Comment: Look into regular expressions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the String.indexOf(String) method to find the first position of the "package" and "class" Strings on the line. Then take the substring from the end of this position to the first semicolon. Something like this:

```
String line;
while ((line = readLine()) != null) {
    String packageName = null, className = null;
    int indexOfPackage = line.indexOf("package");
    int indexOfClass = line.indexOf("class");
    int indexOfBrace = line.indexOf('{');
    int indexOfSemiColon = line.indexOf(';');
    int classStringLength = "class ".length();
    int packageStringLength = "package ".length();
    if (indexOfPackage != -1) {
        packageName = line.substring(indexOfPackage + packageStringLength, indexOfSemiColon);
    }
    if (indexOfClass != -1) {
        className = line.substring(indexOfClass + classStringLength, indexOfBrace);
    }

    System.out.println("Package Name: " + packageName + " ");
    System.out.print("Class Name: " + className + " ");
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot gilbert.can you please explain the line numbers 5 and 8.

Comment: this code is working, but if in worst case someone will add another line after ";" how i ll substring that part.for example                                                              package com.sify;import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;

public class WriteJava{

}
public class WriteJava2{

} in this case the out put is coming as ; Package Name: com.sify;import java.io.BufferedReader; which i dont want. i need the package name only, it should end befor the ';'. Kindly clarify me .

Comment: I have edited the answer to more clearly show what those lines are doing. I also made it more general to restrict the end of the package and class names to the ';' and '{' respectively.